# C# and SQLite : not loading table from DB

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

So I'm trying to allow for data to be input and read from a db in sqlite within a C# application. I already have the data in the table in SQLite and I have tried to setup the connection to the db but for some reason when I try to run the form it is on the build closes down without displaying the form, it will load the intro form but as soon as I try to get into the PDetail form it closes down my application

```
public static List <Player> LoadPlayer()
    {
        using (IDbConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {
            var output = conn.Query<Player>("select * from Player", new DynamicParameters());
            return output.ToList();
        }
    }

    public static void SavePlayer(Player player)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {
            cnn.Execute("insert into Player (Forename, Surname, Position) values (@Forename, @Surname, @Position)", player);
        }
    }


    private static string LoadConnectionString(string id = "Default")
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[id].ConnectionString;
    }
```

Above is what my SqliteAccess class looks like and below is what the form where I want to get the players info and display the players info

```
public PDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LoadPlayerList();
    }

 private void LoadPlayerList()
    {
        playerDetails = SqliteAccess.LoadPlayer();


        WireUpPlayerList();
    }

    private void WireUpPlayerList()
    {

        listBoxPlayers.DataSource = null;
        listBoxPlayers.DataSource = playerDetails ;
        listBoxPlayers.DisplayMember = "PlayerDetails";
    }
```

I have tried following tutorials on youtube but cannot figure out for the life of me what I'm doing wrong I have added a connection string in my app.config. thanks for any help!

Comment: Lots of detail, but not the critical details needed to solve the problem.  Besides a form not loading, what exceptions are being thrown?  If there are no pop ups, check the output log and/or configure the environment exception handling to halt on all exceptions, etc.  Edit the question with precise details.  If none of that works, then add some manual tracing code and/or breakpoints to determine what code is running and where it stops.  Maybe inspecting the code you shared will reveal a problem, but there should be more useful debugging information that you can gather and should include.

Comment: First obvious issue:  The insert statement in `SavePlayer()` contains 3 parameters, but only one object is passed to the `execute()` statement.  Not only that, but it appears to be a custom object, not basic data types which is what will be expected for query parameters.  To my knowledge, there is no automatic mapping between object properties and parameter names.

Comment: @CPerkins I've identified that it is the `playerDetails = SqliteAccess.LoadPlayer();` is the issue if I comment it out the PDetail form runs. So I have no clue what Im doing wrong and no clue what Im doing in general

Comment: General principle when debugging:  Drill into the code as far as you can.  If you identified `LoadPlayer()` as the source, *you have the code--it is your code!*-- so go inside and find out more precisely where the problem is.  Put a break point inside and trace through one line at a time until you get an exception or observe the broken behavior or unexpected value.  If you find the problem is at the line `new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))` then you need to look at the output from `LoadConnectionString()` and see what it is producing.

Comment: Next lesson:  Look at the docs (most likely online).  If you have a method that is not doing what you expect, then always review the parameters and output and confirm that you are using it correctly.  It appears that you're using Dapper since I could not find any other extension method Query<T> on the IDBConnection interface.  Have you looked at the [docs](https://dapper-tutorial.net/query)?  Do you really need `new DynamicParameters()` for a query without parameters?  So many details that you could look into.  That's what debugging is.  Stack Overflow is great *after* you have done all that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be related to your db file. I make a code example according to the code you provided. I add a method CreateDBfile method to create database. It could show the correct data in the listbox.
Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateDBfile();
            LoadPlayerList();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        List<Player> playerDetails = new List<Player>();
        private void LoadPlayerList()
        {
            playerDetails = LoadPlayer();


            WireUpPlayerList();
        }

        private void WireUpPlayerList()
        {

            listBox1.DataSource = null;
            listBox1.DataSource = playerDetails;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Forename";
        }
        public static List<Player> LoadPlayer()
        {
            using (IDbConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
            {
                var output = conn.Query<Player>("select * from Player", new DynamicParameters());
                return output.ToList();
            }
        }

        public static void SavePlayer(Player player)
        {
            using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
            {
                cnn.Execute("insert into Player (Forename, Surname, Position) values (@Forename, @Surname, @Position)", player);
            }
        }


        private static string LoadConnectionString()
        {
            return "Data Source = MyDatabase.sqlite";
        }
        public void CreateDBfile()
        {
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");

            SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite");
            m_dbConnection.Open();

            string sql = "create table Player ([Forename] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, [Surname] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, [Position] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL) ";

            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sql = "insert into  Player(Forename,Surname,Position) values('test1','hello','home')";

            command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sql = "insert into  Player(Forename,Surname,Position) values('test2','hello1','company')";

            command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sql = "insert into  Player(Forename,Surname,Position) values('test3','hello2','school')";

            command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }

    public class Player
    {
        public string Forename { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public string Position { get; set; }

    }
```

Appconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
      <add name="SQLiteDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Result:
[image]